# php print statements in separate lines

Tags: php, printing, lines, separator

The following php script  prints several statements and variables! they print on the sameline! i want to print them in separate lines one after the other! How can i do it?
for example the 1st 2 statements should be printed as:

Programming in PHP is fun

I learnt how to comment in PHP

but currently it prints as
 Programming in PHP is fun I learnt how to comment in PHP

```
?php 

echo "Programming in PHP is fun";

//This is the 1st programming 4 tutorial

/*This tutorial helped me
to gain a good knowledge in php! */

print "I learnt how to comment in PHP";


echo "A variable name must start with a letter or an underscore '_' -- not a number";

echo "A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters, underscores (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and _ )";

echo "A variable name should not contain spaces. If a variable name is more than one word, it should beseparated with an underscore  or with capitalization ";

$name= "My name is XXX";

$number=25;

$float_number=10.245;

$negative_number=-12;

echo($name);

echo($number);

echo($float_number);

echo($negative_number);


$age=24;

$feature =$age;



echo($feature);

$x=45;

$y=12;

echo($x+$y);


$myName="My name is 'Lasith'";

?>
```

Comment: use html `br` tag

Comment: Use `PHP_EOL`. `example:- echo($x+$y).PHP_EOL;`

Comment: For html, it's `<br>`. For text it's `\n` or `\r\n`, which only works in double quotes, or PHP_EOL as Anant suggests, which does not work inside quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you echo them as plain text, add a newline character after each echo:

```
echo "\n";
```

If you echo them to HTML (into a web browser), add a HTML `<br>` tag after each echo:

```
echo "<br>";
```

You can also use string concatenation

```
echo "Programming in PHP is fun" . "\n";
echo "Programming in PHP is fun" . "<br>";
```

or add the newline or `<br>` tag to the string

```
echo "Programming in PHP is fun\n";
echo "Programming in PHP is fun<br>";
```